# How to split the string in to different parts

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to split the string in to different parts. I will have some string which will be generated dynamically which will contains 500 characters. I want to split in to 5 parts. What i mean is i want to take `100` characters in to `array[0]`, next `100` characters in `array[1]` ....

Example:

```
 var string = "kjfaorj.......................................................";
 array[0] = "kjfaorj..... up to 100 characters";
 array[1] = " next 100 characters ";
 ..........................
 ..........................
```

Comment: As a quick answer, I recommend initializing a 5-element array, then populating those elements one at a time using a [`for` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) that loops five times, using [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) with different parameters each time.

Answer (score 5):

```
 if(str.length % 100 == 0) //If the string contains exactly 500 or 400...etc
     count = str.length / 100;
  else
    count = str.length / 100 +1; //If the string contains exactly 505 or 417...etc

for(var i=0;i<count;i++)
  array[i] = s.substring(i*100,(i*100)+(100));
```

Second approach is good for dynamic string

Comment: Put `str.length` in the first statement of `for` for better performance. `for(var i=0, l=str.length; i<l/100+1; i++)`

Comment: it is false.try :  array[i] = s.substring( i*100,(i*100)+(100))

Comment: @AbdennourToumi hey sorry.You are right.Thanks for information

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var string= "kjfaorj.......................................................";
var array=[];
array[0] = string.substring(0,99);
array[1] = string.substring(100,199);
array[2] = string.substring(200,299);
array[3] = string.substring(300,399);
array[4] = string.substring(400,499);
```

Comment: Shouldn't the first one be `array[0] = string.substring(0,99);`?

Answer (score 1):

The following loop will split up any string in pieces of 100 characters.  The last element of the array will contain the remaining number of characters (but never more than 100).
If you’re certain your initial string will contain exactly 500 characters, you’ll always get an array of five elements, each one containing 100 characters.

```
var str = "kjfaorj....................................................... etc.";
for(var arr = [], i = 0; i < str.length - 1; i += 100) {
    arr.push(str.substr(i, 100));
}
```

The difference between [substr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) and [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) is that `substr` expects the *length* of the substring, whereas `substring` expects the first and the last index.

Comment: also, `substr` is non-standard

Comment: @JanDvorak: True, but it _is_ supported by every JS engine. :-)

Answer (score 0):

As i see "jquery" tag in your question,i want to introduce my powerful JQuery Plugin . 
Its [String As JQuery](https://github.com/abdennour/string.as.jquery)
one of features of this plugin is to convert a String to Array : Each n consecutives characters of String is an item in this Array.

**Syntax**

```
var myarray=$(myString).toStrArray(eachN);
```

for you case , you can use it as following ;

```
 var string = "kjfaorj.......................................................";

var myarray=$(string).toStrArray(100);
```

## Demo
http://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/E8LhJ/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more generic function for any string length:

```
function splitupString(str,chunklen){
 str = str.split('');
 var chunks = Array((str.length/chunklen)^0).join(',').split(',');
 return chunks
         .map(function(){return this.splice(0,chunklen).join('');},str)
         .concat(str.join(''));
}
// usage example
var strsplitted = splitupString('123456789012345678901234567890123',5);
//=> [12345,67890,12345,67890,12345,67890,123]
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/gNkUZ/) example

Answer (score 0):

If you need to split the string to exactly 100 characters chunks then

```
var foo = bar.match(/.{100}/g);
```

If you need to split to chunks having no more than 100 characters, then

```
var foo = bar.match(/.{1,100}/g);
```